# Android - I need to create a database to store results using "add event" click button and then reflect these results onto another activity

Tags: android, database, button, onclick

So I have created a form on an activity for the user to fill out including date and time pickers. My issue is that no matter how hard i try I run into issues when attempting to store the details on the edit texts, i believe this is due to the two other dialog buttons in the code.

This is my main display activity with the edit text field i want stored on the database.

```
package selector.sport.finalproject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

import java.util.Calendar;



public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

// Widget GUI
Button btnCalendar, btnTimePicker;
EditText txtDate, txtTime;

// Variable for storing current date and time
private int mYear, mMonth, mDay, mHour, mMinute;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

    btnCalendar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bcalendar);
    btnTimePicker = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btime);

    txtDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eteDate);
    txtTime = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eteTime);

    btnCalendar.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnTimePicker.setOnClickListener(this);
}

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (v == btnCalendar) {

            // Process to get Current Date
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            // Launch Date Picker Dialog
            DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                              int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                            // Display Selected date in textbox
                            txtDate.setText(dayOfMonth + "-"
                                    + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year);

                        }
                    }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
            dpd.show();
        }
        if (v == btnTimePicker) {

            // Process to get Current Time
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

            // Launch Time Picker Dialog
            TimePickerDialog tpd = new TimePickerDialog(this,
                    new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                                              int minute) {
                            // Display Selected time in textbox
                            txtTime.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
                        }
                    }, mHour, mMinute, false);
            tpd.show();
        }

    }



public void openMap(View view) {
    Intent startNewActivity = new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class);
    startActivity(startNewActivity);
}
```

Anyone know how to implement this so that I can get the results on my second activity when the user enters their information and clicks the "add event button"

Here is my xml for the same activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="selector.sport.finalproject.DisplayMessageActivity">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="500dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:id="@+id/sport"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:src="@drawable/sport"
    android:layout_weight="0.52"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/eteName"
    android:hint="Event Name"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/sport"
    />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="date"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/eteDate"
    android:hint="Event Date"
    android:layout_below="@+id/eteName"

    />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="time"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Event Time"
    android:id="@+id/eteTime"
    android:layout_below="@+id/bcalendar"
     />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Number of People"
    android:id="@+id/eteNum"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btime"
    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Create Event"
    android:id="@+id/bcreate"
    android:layout_below="@+id/eteNum"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:onClick="insert" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Show Date Picker"
    android:onClick="setDate"
    android:id="@+id/bcalendar"
    android:layout_below="@+id/eteDate"
     />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Show Time Picker"
    android:onClick="showDialog"
    android:id="@+id/btime"
    android:layout_below="@+id/eteTime"
     />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/bmaps"
    android:onClick="openMap"
    android:src="@drawable/map"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btime"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/sport"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/sport" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Location: "
    android:id="@+id/tvlocation"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/eteDate"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/bmaps"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/bmaps" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Location: "
    android:hint="Location"
    android:id="@+id/eteLocation"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bcreate"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/eteNum" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The onClick values do not match the method name but they should.  Please look under Responding to Click Events.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html

You provided code and what you wanted to accomplish which was great, but no detail about what was blocking you.  The error message or a description of the unwanted behavior is helpful.